# Do not close the mode in the mouse up event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, simplemodal

I use the micro modal js package in my project but I have a problem. this modal closed when occurring mouse down or mouse up event Outside the medal range. but I want mouse-up event Do not do anything and just mouse-down event can close the medal.
this is my HTML code.

```js
let openButton = document.getElementById('open-modal');

openButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    MicroModal.show('modal-1');
});
```

```css
/**************************\
  Basic Modal Styles
\**************************/

.modal {
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,avenir next,avenir,helvetica neue,helvetica,ubuntu,roboto,noto,segoe ui,arial,sans-serif;
}

.modal__overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal__container {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal__title {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #00449e;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal__close {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.modal__header .modal__close:before { content: "\2715"; }

.modal__content {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.modal__btn {
    font-size: .875rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-transform: none;
    overflow: visible;
    line-height: 1.15;
    margin: 0;
    will-change: transform;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease-out;
    transition: transform .25s ease-out;
    transition: transform .25s ease-out,-webkit-transform .25s ease-out;
}

.modal__btn:focus, .modal__btn:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.modal__btn-primary {
    background-color: #00449e;
    color: #fff;
}



/**************************\
  Demo Animation Style
\**************************/
@keyframes mmfadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes mmfadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes mmslideIn {
    from { transform: translateY(15%); }
    to { transform: translateY(0); }
}

@keyframes mmslideOut {
    from { transform: translateY(0); }
    to { transform: translateY(-10%); }
}

.micromodal-slide {
    display: none;
}

.micromodal-slide.is-open {
    display: block;
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="false"] .modal__overlay {
    animation: mmfadeIn .3s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="false"] .modal__container {
    animation: mmslideIn .3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="true"] .modal__overlay {
    animation: mmfadeOut .3s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="true"] .modal__container {
    animation: mmslideOut .3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide .modal__container,
.micromodal-slide .modal__overlay {
    will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <Title>MicroModal Toggle Pen</Title>
    <script defer  src="https://unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js"></script>
    <script  defer  src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="open-modal">Open new modal</button>

<!-- New event modal -->
<div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
        <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
            <header class="modal__header">
                <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                    New event
                </h2>
                <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
            </header>
            <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name">
            </main>
            <footer class="modal__footer">
                <button class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button class="modal__btn" data-micromodal-close aria-label="Close this dialog window">Close</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Event 1 -->
<div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="event-modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
        <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
            <header class="modal__header">
                <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                    Event 1
                </h2>
                <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
            </header>
            <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                Blah
            </main>
            <footer class="modal__footer">
                <button class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button class="modal__btn" data-micromodal-close aria-label="Close this dialog window">Close</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Event Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="event-modal-2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
        <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
            <header class="modal__header">
                <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                    Event 2
                </h2>
                <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
            </header>
            <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                blah
            </main>
            <footer class="modal__footer">
                <button class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button class="modal__btn" data-micromodal-close aria-label="Close this dialog window">Close</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Sounds like an issue to report at https://github.com/ghosh/Micromodal/issues

Comment: There is a scourge of modals on the internet that close on mouse up. Any time I click drag to select a text field in one of those modals, inevitably my mouse goes outside the modal closing everything and deleting all the info in the form that I had filled in. So freaking annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want prevent modal from closing when `mouseup` originated on different element than `mousedown` (aka when selecting text and cursor moved outside of modal or opposite - moved into modal), but still want be able close modal when it clicked on overlay itself, than you can use this:

```js
let openButton = document.getElementById('open-modal');

openButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    MicroModal.show('modal-1');
});

const overlays = document.querySelectorAll(".modal__overlay");
for(let i = 0; i < overlays.length; i++)
{
  const overlay = overlays[i];
  let overlayMouseDown;

  /* detect if clicked on overlay itself */
  overlay.addEventListener("mousedown", e => overlayMouseDown = e.target === overlay);
  /* prevent from closing when clicked on overlay and dragged into modal */
  overlay.addEventListener("mouseout", e => overlayMouseDown = false);
  overlay.addEventListener("click", e =>
  {
    if (e.target === overlay && !overlayMouseDown)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/**************************\
  Basic Modal Styles
\**************************/

.modal {
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,avenir next,avenir,helvetica neue,helvetica,ubuntu,roboto,noto,segoe ui,arial,sans-serif;
}

.modal__overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal__container {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal__title {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #00449e;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal__close {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.modal__header .modal__close:before { content: "\2715"; }

.modal__content {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.modal__btn {
    font-size: .875rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-transform: none;
    overflow: visible;
    line-height: 1.15;
    margin: 0;
    will-change: transform;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease-out;
    transition: transform .25s ease-out;
    transition: transform .25s ease-out,-webkit-transform .25s ease-out;
}

.modal__btn:focus, .modal__btn:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.modal__btn-primary {
    background-color: #00449e;
    color: #fff;
}



/**************************\
  Demo Animation Style
\**************************/
@keyframes mmfadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes mmfadeOut {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes mmslideIn {
    from { transform: translateY(15%); }
    to { transform: translateY(0); }
}

@keyframes mmslideOut {
    from { transform: translateY(0); }
    to { transform: translateY(-10%); }
}

.micromodal-slide {
    display: none;
}

.micromodal-slide.is-open {
    display: block;
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="false"] .modal__overlay {
    animation: mmfadeIn .3s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="false"] .modal__container {
    animation: mmslideIn .3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="true"] .modal__overlay {
    animation: mmfadeOut .3s cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide[aria-hidden="true"] .modal__container {
    animation: mmslideOut .3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1);
}

.micromodal-slide .modal__container,
.micromodal-slide .modal__overlay {
    will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <Title>MicroModal Toggle Pen</Title>
    <script defer  src="https://unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js"></script>
    <script  defer  src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="open-modal">Open new modal</button>

<!-- New event modal -->
<div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
        <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
            <header class="modal__header">
                <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                    New event
                </h2>
                <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
            </header>
            <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name">
            </main>
            <footer class="modal__footer">
                <button class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button class="modal__btn" data-micromodal-close aria-label="Close this dialog window">Close</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Event 1 -->
<div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="event-modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
        <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
            <header class="modal__header">
                <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                    Event 1
                </h2>
                <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
            </header>
            <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                Blah
            </main>
            <footer class="modal__footer">
                <button class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button class="modal__btn" data-micromodal-close aria-label="Close this dialog window">Close</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Event Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="event-modal-2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
        <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
            <header class="modal__header">
                <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
                    Event 2
                </h2>
                <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
            </header>
            <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                blah
            </main>
            <footer class="modal__footer">
                <button class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button class="modal__btn" data-micromodal-close aria-label="Close this dialog window">Close</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to remove `data-micromodal-close` from your `modal__overlay`. Doing that will prevent the modal from closing when you click on the backdrop.

```
<div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1">
```

Only put `data-micromodal-close` on elements that should dismiss the modal when clicked, like the close button.

https://github.com/ghosh/micromodal/issues/132#issuecomment-478688942

Answer (score 0):

i first removed data-micromodal-close from modal__overlay and then i wrote this js code

```js
let openButton = document.getElementById('open-modal');
const modalOverlay = document.querySelector('.modal__overlay');
openButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    MicroModal.show('modal-1');
});

modalOverlay.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    if (e.target.closest('.modal__container'))
        return;
    MicroModal.close('modal-1');
});
```